# I don't understand why the code is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-queryset

here is the error:

```py
>>> from blog.models import Post

>>> user = User.objects.get(username='admin')

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>

NameError: name 'User' is not defined

>>>
```

here is the model:

```
from django.db import models

from django.utils import timezone

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

class Post(models.Model):

  class Status(models.TextChoices):

    DRAFT = 'DF', 'Draft'

    PUBLISHED = 'PB', 'Published'

  title = models.CharField(max_length=250)

  slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250)

  author = models.ForeignKey(

    User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='blog_posts'

  )

  body = models.TextField()

  publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

  created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

  updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

  status = models.CharField(max_length=2,choices=Status.choices,default=Status.DRAFT)

  class Meta:

    ordering = ['-publish']

    indexes = [models.Index(fields=['-publish']),]

    

  def __str__(self):

    return self.title
```

I tried to change this part of the code '
'to this 'from django.contrib.auth.models import User' but it did not help

Comment: You did not import it in the shell...

Comment: @WillemVOsupportsmodstrike , How is it?I didn't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running this before running `user = User.objects.get(username='admin')`:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

Hope this helps!